# rocket.chat uploading to inaccessible room

Tags: node.js, rocket.chat

I am writing a slashcommand with the `Rocket.Chat.Apps-engine` for my Rocket.Chat Server which exports the chat in the current room, creates a pdf and uploads this back into the room. I am using an own node server for the generation and upload. However, my `bot-user` does not have access to lets say direct chats, private rooms also not. One could invite the bot into every new private room, but the direct chat problem stays. Is there a ways to somehow use the Rest Api to write a message to such rooms? I am using access tokens for authorization.

So far I can read all the chats with the `/api/v1/im.messages.others` endpoint (also those my bot cannot access), now I need to have some endpoint or similar to write something to the rooms which my bot cannot see.